# AVCaptureSession record audio from bluetooth microphone

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth

From searching today I think it is still not possible to use a Bluetooth headset microphone as the audio input for an AVCaptureSession (video recording) on an iOS device even with the audio changes made in iOS7. However in case I just haven't looked hard enough has anyone found a way to achieve this?

According to the apple docs kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput can be set for the kAudioSessionCategory_RecordAudio or kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord categories. However the AudioSessionSetProperty method required to do this has been depreciated.  Ignoring that and just using it I still can't find a way to utilize this to get the bluetooth audio passed to a video recording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this to work in iOS7+ by configuring the audio session associated with my AVCapture session:

```
    AVCaptureSession *cs = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    self.captureSession = cs;

    self.captureSession.usesApplicationAudioSession = true;
    self.captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = true;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this when I re-visit the project soon...!

Comment: How can I to add an AVCaptureDeviceInput with this code? My current project require AVCaptureDeviceInput for record video with audio. @Adam Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I solved same problem by setting 'automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession' to 'NO'.

But it would cause background music very low without airpods. And i fixed it by adding 'AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker' to options.

This is my code:

```
self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
self.captureSession.usesApplicationAudioSession = YES;
self.captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = NO;
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                                withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker
                                                           |AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
                                                      error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"setCategory error：%@", error);
    return NO;
}
```